# convert file path from windows to linux and back again, using boost::filesystem

Tags: c++, linux, windows, path, boost-filesystem

Is it me, or does boost::filesystem::path::make_preferred not convert "\" to "/"?

> davidan@kempt:~/Documents/prog/work!$ ../practice/./path_info c:\pitou foo/bar\baa.txt
>   composed path:
>    cout << -------------: "c:pitou/foo/bar\baa.txt"
>    make_preferred()----------: "c:pitou/foo/bar\baa.txt"

I was rather hoping for

> c:\pitou\foo\bar\baa.txt

on windows and

> /pitou/foo/bar/baa.txt

(or something close) on POSIX

the source is here: [boost::filesystem tutorial](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/filesystem/example/path_info.cpp)

Comment: can't you use usual environment variables e.g. `HOME` and `getenv` them?

Comment: included in path.hpp:  ># ifdef BOOST_WINDOWS_API
    typedef wchar_t                        value_type;  
    BOOST_STATIC_CONSTEXPR value_type      preferred_separator = L'\\';  
# else  
    typedef char                           value_type;  
    BOOST_STATIC_CONSTEXPR value_type      preferred_separator = '/';  
# endif    So this should already be addressed, non ?

Comment: non, it isn't... >>path& make_preferred();
Effects: The contained pathname is converted to the preferred native format. [Note: On Windows, the effect is to replace slashes with backslashes. On POSIX, there is no effect. -- end note]                  I ended up having to do it by hand with std::replace in an ifdef posix condition

Comment: I could not make make_preferred works too. However I did solved my problem using path.string() (take a look at http://theboostcpplibraries.com/boost.filesystem-paths). I hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

Ended up doing it this way:

```
string f = filename;
#       ifdef BOOST_POSIX_API   //workaround for user-input files
            std::replace(f.begin(), f.end(), '\\', '/');        
#       endif
```

There must be a reason why this isn't already handled...?

Answer (score 3):

The reason it is not handled on Linux is explained nicely here:

http://theboostcpplibraries.com/boost.filesystem-paths

Quote:

> If Example 35.5 is executed on Linux, the returned values are
>   different. Most of the member functions return an empty string, except
>   relative_path() and filename(), which return "C:\Windows\System". This
>   means that the string “C:\Windows\System” is interpreted as a file
>   name on Linux, which is understandable given that it is neither a
>   portable encoding of a path nor a platform-dependent encoding on
>   Linux. Therefore, Boost.Filesystem has no choice but to interpret it
>   as a file name.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't use `boost` but I implemented both conversion directions manually.

`FileSystemPathUtils.hpp`:

```
#pragma once

#include <string>

static const char *const WSL_FILE_PATH_HEADER = "/mnt";
static const char WINDOWS_FILE_PATH_SEPARATOR = '\\';
static const char UNIX_FILE_PATH_SEPARATOR = '/';

std::string windows_to_unix_file_path(std::string file_path, bool is_wsl = true);

std::string unix_to_windows_file_path(std::string file_path, bool is_wsl = true);

std::string windows_path_to_host_operating_system_path(std::string file_path, bool is_wsl = true);
```

`FileSystemPathUtils.cpp`:

```
#include "FileSystemPathUtils.hpp"

#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <sstream>
#include <utility>
#include <cstring>

std::string windows_to_unix_file_path(std::string file_path, bool is_wsl) {
    // Replace the slashes
    std::replace(file_path.begin(), file_path.end(), WINDOWS_FILE_PATH_SEPARATOR, UNIX_FILE_PATH_SEPARATOR);

    // Convert the drive letter to lowercase
    std::transform(file_path.begin(), file_path.begin() + 1, file_path.begin(),
                   [](unsigned char character) {
                       return std::tolower(character);
                   });

    // Remove the colon
    const auto drive_letter = file_path.substr(0, 1);
    const auto remaining_path = file_path.substr(2, file_path.size() - 2);
    file_path = drive_letter + remaining_path;

    std::stringstream stringstream;

    if (is_wsl) {
        stringstream << WSL_FILE_PATH_HEADER;
    }

    stringstream << "/";
    stringstream << file_path;

    return stringstream.str();
}

std::string unix_to_windows_file_path(std::string file_path, bool is_wsl) {
    if (is_wsl) {
        file_path = file_path.erase(0, strlen(WSL_FILE_PATH_HEADER));
    }

    // Delete the leading forward slash
    file_path.erase(0, 1);

    // Convert the drive letter to uppercase
    std::transform(file_path.begin(), file_path.begin() + 1, file_path.begin(),
                   [](unsigned char character) {
                       return std::toupper(character);
                   });

    // Replace the slashes
    std::replace(file_path.begin(), file_path.end(), UNIX_FILE_PATH_SEPARATOR,
                 WINDOWS_FILE_PATH_SEPARATOR);

    std::stringstream stringstream;
    stringstream << file_path.at(0);
    stringstream << ":";
    stringstream << file_path.substr(1, file_path.size() - 1);

    return stringstream.str();
}

std::string windows_path_to_host_operating_system_path(std::string file_path, bool is_wsl) {
#ifdef _WIN32
    return file_path;

#else
    return windows_to_unix_file_path(std::move(file_path), is_wsl);

#endif
}
```